# What is this attacker trying to do by making edits to Stack Exchange posts?

Tags: sql-injection, websites

While reviewing the suggested edits for the Personal Finance & Money Stack Exchange site, I came across some strange proposed edits:

**Example 1**:

[image: Suggested edit 1]

**Example 2**:

[image: Suggested edit 2]

This looks like some kind of attempt at attacking the website. Could you explain how this attack is supposed to work? I see a PostgreSQL-specific `SELECT` in example 2, so is this an attempted SQL injection attack? What is the meaning of `&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;`? I don't see anything destructive here.

Comment: `&#xD;&#xA;` = ASCII `0xD 0xA` = `\r\n` = carriage return +  line feed In the end this edit looks like bad editor or a test (but for a test it would be easier to simply create a new question instead of edit one).

Comment: Possibly a bot that is correcting grammar / format ... and it has bugs? in example 1 it also attempt to replace the ' w/ an ESC?!?! ... prob just a bug, not malicious

Comment: @CaffeineAddiction: `&#x27;` is _hex_ 27 which is apostrophe; `&#27;` would be decimal for ESCape. However, HTML (and XML) also has `&apos;` which is usually preferred as clearer to people in places where you need an entity, which in body text you don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like someone is fuzzing StackExchange - passing potentially malicious data as input in an attempt to uncover any vulnerabilities in the handling of this input data.

In these particular instances, it seems the attacker is testing the Edit Summary field. The first example contains `OR 2+622-622-1=0+0+0+1`. This is an obfuscated way of saying `OR 1=1`, which is commonly used in SQL injection payloads. It is difficult to think of any benign use of this SQL statement, so I think that pretty much rules out a buggy bot. In the second example, the attacker appears to test for [time based blind sql injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Blind_SQL_Injection#time-based).

The edits in the bodies are simply replacing characters with their HTML entities equivalents (apostrophe with `&#x27;`, newlines with `&#xD;&#xA;`). This is probably just to get over the minimum suggested edit character limit.

Comment: What is the purpose of `OR 1=1` in SQL injection payloads?

Comment: @Flux It's often used as a login bypass. See: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/210115/235964. I'm not sure exactly what the attacker intended it to do in this case though.